# Filter out video links from Reddit

Tags: reddit

I would like to see all link posts linking to videos gone from Reddit as I see it, in the Home tab and when browsing specific subs. If detecting a video isn't possible than just getting rid of all links to YouTube specifically would be pretty much just as good.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible without writing your own browser extension.

Comment: Neither do I. That's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Reddit Enhancement Suite](https://redditenhancementsuite.com/) browser extension. Go to filteReddit in settings ([direct link](https://www.reddit.com/#res:settings/filteReddit)) and add a keyword `youtube.com` under "domains". Remember to press "save options" on the top right corner.

[image: screenshot]

You can add an unlimited number of additional domains — `v.redd.it`, `youtube.com` and `twitch.tv` alone should hide over 90% of video submissions.